# Find object value use it to replace a string found before another object and save to txt file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a log file like this:

```
[2016/05/27 23:46:13.554-04:00][VERBOSE] 5.0.0 : AzCopy /Source:c:\test /Dest:https://mywebsite.blob.core.windows.net/monitoring /DestKey:****** /S /SetContentType /V:C:\azcopy1.log
[2016/05/27 23:46:14.179-04:00][VERBOSE] Start transfer: testfolder\file1.txt => testfolder/file1.txt
[2016/05/27 23:46:14.320-04:00][VERBOSE] Start transfer: testfolder\file2.png => testfolder/file2.png
[2016/05/27 23:46:14.320-04:00][VERBOSE] Start transfer: testfolder\file3.bmp => testfolder/file3.bmp
[2016/05/27 23:46:15.195-04:00][VERBOSE] Finished transfer: testfolder\file1.txt => testfolder/file1.txt
[2016/05/27 23:46:15.210-04:00][VERBOSE] Finished transfer: testfolder\file3.bmp => testfolder/file3.bmp
[2016/05/27 23:46:19.335-04:00][VERBOSE] Finished transfer: testfolder\file2.png => testfolder/file2.png
[2016/05/27 23:46:19.351-04:00] Transfer summary:
-----------------
Total files transferred: 3
Transfer successfully:   3
Transfer skipped:        0
Transfer failed:         0
Elapsed time:            00.00:00:05
```

I need to output result like this into a new file:

```
https://mywebsite.blob.core.windows.net/monitoring/testfolder/file1.txt
https://mywebsite.blob.core.windows.net/monitoring/testfolder/file3.bmp
https://mywebsite.blob.core.windows.net/monitoring/testfolder/file2.png
```

All i managed to do is this:

```
Get-Content C:\azcopy1.log | Where-Object { $_.Contains("Finished transfer:") } | Set-Content C:\listoflinks.txt
```

But that only gives me result like this:

```
[2016/05/27 23:46:15.195-04:00][VERBOSE] Finished transfer: testfolder\file1.txt => testfolder/file1.txt
[2016/05/27 23:46:15.210-04:00][VERBOSE] Finished transfer: testfolder\file3.txt => testfolder/file3.txt
[2016/05/27 23:46:19.335-04:00][VERBOSE] Finished transfer: testfolder\file2.txt => testfolder/file2.txt
```

Comment: So what did you try to manipulate the strings?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
$a = '[2016/05/27 23:46:19.335-04:00][VERBOSE] Finished transfer: testfolder\file2.png => testfolder/file2.png'
$a | ? {$_.Contains("Finished transfer:")} | % {'https://mywebsite.blob.core.windows.net/monitoring/' + ($_ -replace '.*=> (.*)', '$1').trim()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know almost nothing about poweshell commands (or any commands in general), so all i can do is to find codes on internet for individual operations and run them 1 by 1 to get the desired result, so my code is very long, but it does what i need, here is how i managed to get the desired result:

First i extracted the line with root url:

```
Get-Content C:\azcopy1.log | Where-Object { $_.Contains("http") } | Set-Content C:\mainurl.txt
```

Then i removed everything from that line upto http string (i know that this code is designed to work with multiple lines, but i didn't find anything better):

```
$text = ( Get-Content C:\mainurl.txt | Out-String ).Trim() 
$text.Substring(0,$text.IndexOf(' /DestKey')) | Set-Content C:\mainurl.txt
$out = "C:\mainurl.txt"
$lines = get-content "C:\mainurl.txt"
foreach ($line in $lines)
{
    $len = $line.length
    $PipePos = $line.indexof("http")
    $retChars = ($len - $PipePos)
    $return = $line.Substring($len - $retchars, $retChars)
    out-file $out -inputobject $return
}
```

Next i extracted all lines that include uploaded filenames:

```
Get-Content C:\azcopy1.log | Where-Object { $_.Contains("Finished transfer:") } | Set-Content C:\listoflinkstemp.txt
```

After that i have removed everything from each line upto string =>

```
$out = "c:\listoflinks.txt"
$lines = get-content "C:\listoflinkstemp.txt"
foreach ($line in $lines)
{
    $len = $line.length
    $PipePos = $line.indexof("=> ")
    $retChars = ($len - $PipePos)
    $return = $line.Substring($len - $retchars, $retChars)
    out-file $out -inputobject $return -append
}
```

and finaly i took the main root url and replaced it by => string in every line in list of uploaded file names:

```
$mainurl = get-content "C:\mainurl.txt"
$string = get-content "c:\listoflinks.txt"
$string.Replace("=> ","$mainurl/") | Set-Content c:\listoflinks.txt
Remove-Item c:\listoflinkstemp.txt
```

I'm sure that all this can be done with couple of lines of codes, but as i said my knowledge is very limited and i don't know how to make the code shorter, what i did, get the job done so...